# PHP - correct ternary implementation

Tags: php, syntax

Ok,

so consider the following:

```
$this->foo = isset($_GET['foo']) && !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : NULL;
```

and this:

```
$this->foo = (isset($_GET['foo']) && !empty($_GET['foo'])) ? $_GET['foo'] : NULL;
```

When I write an if / else statement with multiple checks, I generally include the extra parenthesis as in the second example. In the ternary, both examples work.

Should I add the extra parenthesis as on the bottom? Or go with the first?

Thanks

Comment: There is no functional difference in the code, go with what ever makes it more readable for you. Generally I think it's better to have more parenthesis, as it makes reading the code later easier.

Comment: Doesn't matter both are correct, I myself always add the parenthesis because I find it more readable.

Comment: Both correct, personally I would use the second method:)

Comment: Both are right but second one is more readable and according to stander-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence is the issue as to when parenthesis are *necessary* (notwithstanding readability).

When dealing with the *ternary* operator look at the order PHP uses to group expressions, start with the ternary operator(s) and examine the operators that are grouped *after* the ternary operator. Those are the operators that have the potential to produce erroneous output.

[PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), starting with ternary:

```
Assoc.  Operators                   Additional Information
...
left    ? :                         ternary
right   = += -= *= **= /= .= %=  
        &= %= &= |= ^= <<= >>= =>   assignment
left    and                         logical
left    xor                         logical
left    or                          logical
left    ,                           many uses
```

In this case there are the assignment operators, the lower precedence logical operators, and comma.

It appears the ternary and assignment are equal, therefore grouping is determined by their *associativity* when the two are in the same statement.

```
$a = true? 'yes': 'no';
// $a is assigned 'yes'
```

*Assignment* is right associative so, in relation to the `=`, expressions are grouped right to left. In this case the ternary comes first (rightmost) and the statement works as expected.

That leaves the lower precedence boolean and the comma.

```
echo true and true? 'yes': 'no';
// Echos: 1
// Grouped like: echo true and (true? 'yes': 'no');
```

Not as expected. Use parenthesis to force intended grouping:

```
echo (true and true)? 'yes': 'no';
// Echos: yes
```

When using *higher precedence* boolean operators, which are grouped before the ternary operator, parenthesis are not necessary.

```
echo true && true? 'yes': 'no';
// Echos: yes
```

Bottom line, when operator precedence is unclear, or readability is desired, use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

[The PSR-2 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) specifically omits any opinion on operators. But in this case, i'll go with the simple one:

```
$this->foo = isset($_GET['foo']) && !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am for the first approach:

```
$this->foo = isset($_GET['foo']) && !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : NULL;
```

simplified to

```
$this->foo = !empty($_GET['foo']) ? $_GET['foo'] : NULL;
```

`empty` already check the `isset`. I would include parathenis in this case only when condition has more then 3 statements. Consider that the 1 line if/else normally is used when the condition is simple, other wise to have a more readable if else you should go with classic `if {} else {}`